About the appearance of Dharma and Adharma
Well, most of us know Dharma and Adharma, the embodients of good and evil and also the mind-born sons of Brahma.
Some people know that Dharma is assumes the form of Lord Shiva's Ox.
But, what is his physical appearance and what about Adharma's appearance?

Most of us know Dharma and Adharma?
What is the basis of this conclusion? Dharma changes based on Upadhi (physical form and position), Desha (place), and Kaalam (times). So, are we born with a commandment book?
Adharma is not an entity separate from Dharma, just like Darkness is the absence of light and not a separate entity. Adharma is when a choice is made among a wide spectrum of possibilities that is lower in degree to the best dharmic action. In Kali Yuga the choices made by humans are lesser in degree to the Dharmic choices made during Satya Yuga, and a bull is used as an example to represent the 4 legs/pillars that uphold the society. Bull (rishabha) is a Vedic term used to describe strength, potency, masculinity, social strength/prosperity, and more. So when Dharma crumbles, so will these aspects of society. While the Bull is represented this way, a Cow is represented as a Pious and Noble being (Aryan). In the absence of Dharma, such noble beings struggle to survive in such a society. A good narration of this concept can be found in Srimad Bhagavatam describing Parikshit's kingship.
So what is a dharmic action?

“Dharyate anena iti dharma” That which is the very basis on which the
Natural, Social and Cosmic phenomenon sustains is Dharma. We will look
at these aspects in detail. (Matruvani
“codaṇā-lakṣaṇaḥ arthaḥ dharmaḥ” That which leads to the cumulative
wellbeing of all the surroundings. Mīmāṃs /Rishi Jaimini)

Mind Born Son of Brahma, Is an attribute given to only Rishi Vasistha. One can consider the 4 Kumaras (Sanaka, Sanandana, Sanatana and Sanat) in a similar way. The concept of Good and Evil is an Abrahamic template.
Source:Here is the source and a detailed understanding of Dharma with examples.

Dharma according sriman madhvacharya is action by which one is taken more towards the Lord sri krishna, on otherhand adharma is the one action which takes one more away from Lord sri krishna. now coming to diety Dharma is yamaraj, in turn lord shiva.. For adharma deity is Kali purusa.. and his vahan is donkey..
https://vedicfeed.com/kali-purush/#:~:text=Kalki%20Purana%20describes

Actually, Yama and Dharmadeva are separate entities. I asked about the appearance of Dharmadeva, not Yama. And, you answered Kali Purusha as deity. Do you have any reference for it  other than Kalki Purana (i don't believe it, because it's not authentic)?

Thanks for Sanatana Dhara for explain about concepts of Dharma and Adharma(not just for me, but for those to understand it). Now, coming to the point:-
As for Dharmadeva, the below experct Brahma Vaivarta Purana mentioned the appearance of Dharmadeva-

Thereafter out of the chest of Krshna, a divine figure of white complexion wearing the locks of hair over his heads. He wore a serene smile over his face. He was witness to all the deeds of all the creatures, was the knower of everything, who always remained unmoved, having good nature, devoid of anger and terror, filled with knowledge and Dharma, quite religious, religion of the religious people and was the great soul and the bestower of the reward, He then stood before Lord Krsna and then prostrated before him and started offering his prayer for him.

Reference: Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Chapter 3

Note: Answer will update if Adharma's appearance is found or this note will be deleted, if not available
